# GlassFish server Error class File.MikTex Not Found

Tags: glassfish

Am getting This  error While  starting Glassfish Server with command  (asadmin start-domain)
I have configured JDK path in asnev.bat file also but still problem persist
(attaching Images for both)

[image][image]

Comment: Are you sure that this is a freshly downloaded and extracted Glassfish archive? When I google for "miktex" I don't see how this can be related to Glassfish.

Comment: And you really should not paste screenshots but rather copy the text from your screen.

Comment: Yes i have downloaded fresh zip file

Comment: Can you take a look at the `server.log` file? Looks like either the classpath or library path is messed up. They should be printed to the log file on startup.